# How to invoke another intent within the responseBuilder WITHOUT using .addDelegateDirective or .addElicitSlotDirective

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, ask-sdk

I have the following return statement:

```js
return input.responseBuilder
  .speak(speakOutput)
  .addDelegateDirective(previousIntent)
  .getResponse();
```

I don't want to use `Dialog.Delegate` (addDelegateDirective) since I need to have access to the ssml output for my repeat intent.

I know you can use `addElicitSlotDirective` but you need to pass a `slotToElicit` - which is not what I want. I just need to have a `speakOutput` and then send the user to another intent. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is just pass some data between intents - you can use [`SessionAttributes`](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/manage-skill-session-and-session-attributes.html) in that case.